# AVG on grouped data throwing ERROR 1046:Use an Explicit Cast

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a `MAP` of data in a txt file:

```
[age#27,height#5.8]
[age#25,height#5.3]
[age#27,height#5.10]
[age#25,height#5.1]
```

I want to display the average height for each group of age.

This is the `LAOD` statement:

```
records = LOAD '~/Documents/Pig_Map.txt' AS (details:map[]);
records: {details: map[]}
```

Then I grouped the data based on age:

```
group_data = GROUP records BY details#'age';
group_data: {group: bytearray,records: {(details: map[])}}
```

for accessing the `details` I did a `FLATTEN` like this (NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS STEP):

```
flatten_records = FOREACH group_data GENERATE group,FLATTEN(records);
flatten_records: {group: bytearray,records::details: map[]}
```

`DUMP flatten_records` this give me the below output:

```
(25,[height#5.1,age#25])
(25,[height#5.3,age#25])
(27,[height#5.10,age#27])
(27,[height#5.8,age#27])
```

Now I want to get the average height; I tried this:

```
display_records = FOREACH flatten_records GENERATE group,AVG(records.details#'height');
```

The error is:

```
<line 10, column 57> Multiple matching functions for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG with input schema: ({{(bytearray)}}, {{(double)}}). Please use an explicit cast.
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
records = LOAD '~/Documents/Pig_Map.txt' AS (details:map[]);
records1 = FOREACH records GENERATE details#'age' AS age,details#'height' AS height;
group_data = GROUP records1 BY age;
display_records = FOREACH group_data GENERATE group,AVG(records1.height);
dump display_records;
```

**Output:**

```
(25,5.199999999999999)
(27,5.449999999999999)
```